# RichTextBox C# programmatically trigger certain functions

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I want to trigger the following functions programmatically in my RichTextBox Editor.

I have this already:

```
//Copy   
TextRange range = new TextRange(doc.Editor.Selection.Start, doc.Editor.Selection.End);
                Clipboard.SetText(range.Text);
    //Paste  
     Editor.Paste();
   // PageDown 
     Editor.PageDown();
   // PageUp     
     Editor.PageUp();
    //Text Size 
     Editor.FontSize = number;
    //Undo    
     Editor.Undo();
    //Redo    
     Editor.Redo();
```

I want to apply the following to the currently selected text on a RichTextBox:

> AlignLeft
>   
> AlignRight
>   
> Center
>   
> Increase/Decrease line spacing
>   
> Bold
>   
> Underline
>   
> Italic

Comment: Do you want to bold/italicize/underline/etc selected text, all text, or any text that you're about to type?

Comment: @Vladislav Selected Text

Comment: I've expanded my answer, to apply the missing styles to a TextRange. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, there are two ways to set a `RichTextBox`'s text styles.

One of them is by changing styles of the control's paragraphs. This only works on paragraphs - not selections.

You get at a collection of blocks, which can be casted to paragraphs, through the `.Document.Blocks` property of the `RichTextBox`. Here's a code sample that applies some styling to the first paragraph.

```
Paragraph firstParagraph = Editor.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock as Paragraph;
firstParagraph.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
firstParagraph.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
firstParagraph.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
firstParagraph.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
firstParagraph.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
firstParagraph.TextIndent = 10;
firstParagraph.LineHeight = 20;
```

When possible, this is the preferred way of applying styles. Although it does require you to write more code, it provides compile-time type checking.

[The other, would be to apply them to a text range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textrange.applypropertyvalue.aspx)

This permits you to apply styles to a selection, but is not type-checked.

```
TextRange selectionRange = Editor.Selection as TextRange;
selectionRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
selectionRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty, FontStyles.Italic);
selectionRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Underline);
selectionRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Paragraph.LineHeightProperty, 45.0);
selectionRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Paragraph.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right);
```

**Be very careful to always pass correct types to the ApplyPropertyValue function, as it does not support compile-time type checking.**

For instance, if the LineHeightProperty were set to `45`, which is an `Int32`, instead of the expected `Double`, you will get a run-time `ArgumentException`.

Comment: Thank you :)  whats the property for underline?

Comment: Of all things, it is `Inline.TextDecorationsProperty`, with a value of `TextDecorations.Underline`