# Underline selection only in RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, selection, richtextbox, underline

I am implementing basic formatting functionality (bold, italic, underline) to a RichTextBox in WPF by means of buttons that trigger such functionality (see my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114109/detect-when-caret-position-changes-in-richtextbox) if you need some context).

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7014700/983064), I can apply underlining by something like the following:

```
selectionRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Underline);
```

The problem is that this seems to apply the underline to the entire `Inline`. For example, if I have the text "`Chuck Norris`", and I only highlight "`Norris`", then the whole of "`Chuck Norris`" gets highlighted when I click the underline button.

This problem does not apply to bold and italic since I am using `TextElement.FontWeightProperty` and `TextElement.FontStyleProperty`, but when using `Inline.TextDecorationsProperty` I get the problem I just described.

Is there any way to make the underline apply only to the selected text, and not to the entire `Inline`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
richTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Underline);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split the inline into separate [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.run(v=vs.110).aspx)'s, and apply the underline the run that represents the selection.